# Pass forms user to SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, forms-authentication

I have an MVC WebApp which is based on the Vs2015 standard template. I am using Forms authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

and the localDB with Integrated Security:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-test;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-test.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For a trigger in the SQL database I would like to access the user which is currently logged into the WebApp via forms. However, the SQL `system_user` returns my current Windows login. Is there any best practice way to access user which is logged into the WebApp via Forms in the database?

I read a lot of articles about impersonation. Though, all of them seem to have the opposite problem: They would like to show the Windows user in the database. 
Can I use impersonation to pass the forms user? Or is there a way to pass the current WebApp user to the connection string with disabled Integrated Security?

Comment: If it is a wen app over internet, possibly you have only one windows user to connect to database. 
If it is in a small internal web app and each user connect to the web app using windows auth, you can use user info inside the trigger?
You can impersonate if you have windows username/password and you need to use Integrated Security. But if you want to differentiate users, why impersonation? just use integrated security. Actually, to me, it is not clear what are you going to do

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Eventually the App should go somewhere into the Web. I would like to authenticate the users via forms, and I would like to access the user credentials in the SQL database. I am rather new to the topic so I have not yet a full grasp of how the SQL connection will look in the end, that is, connect with user credentials or use and admin account and pass the user credentials somehow differently.

Comment: when you use form auth, your app will ask user to enter their windows username/password defined on windows server (or you have to pass it to server). Those username should be defined in SQL server logins and have necessary permissions to be able to work. "Integrated Security=SSPI" is equal to "Integrated Security=true" which means your app connects to SQL Server using windows user

Comment: So yes, I am using the whole `OAuthWebSecurity` which comes with the standard MVC template. I am trying to avoid registering every user in the IIS but rather have an admin account do the connection. However, similar to impersonation I would like to track the actual logged in user in the database. I was wondering if there is a nice way to do that. If not, how would the connection string need to look like if this is not possible, that is that the connection string dynamically uses the current user rather than a static one defined in the string.

Comment: I think if you impersonate USER1 to USER2, then there is no USER1 anymore. and your app only sees USER2. to be able to track connected user at database level, you need to use "Integrated Seurity=true" and not use impersonation. I think if you want to use Admin account in background and still track the connected user/operator, your app should only use WebService or WebAPI and pass user information to every single API. To my knowledge there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found is to use `SET CONTEXT_INFO`, which does exactly what I would like it to do. The downside of this is that one needs to pass the current User ID to every function in the repository, as I did not find a way to automatically pass it to the connection (constructor).

I will update this answers if I find a way to pass the user from the controller to the Model Container.

(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx)